Sequence of connected subsets of X
Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of connected subsets of a topological space $X$ such that for each integer $n \geq 1$, the set $A_n$ has at least one point in common with one of the preceding sets $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_{n-1}$. Prove that the union
$
U = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n
$
is connected.
I tried tackling it by the easy case, assuming that $A_{n} \cap A_{n+1}$ is non-empty for $\forall n\geq 1$ and it was fairly easy.

I think you can just use induction. If the condition is satisfied by ${A_i}_{i\leq n-1}$, and $A_n$ meets (say) $A_k$, then replacing $A_k$ with $A_k\cup A_n$ produces a collection of $n-1$ sets also satisfying the condition.

We first recall that the relation "$x\sim y$: $x$ and $y$ are in the same connected component" is an equivalence relation over $U$. Let's denote $U_N = \bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n$ for any $N\in \mathbb N$.
We now aim to prove the following claim by induction:
for $N\in \mathbb N$, let $P(N)$:"$U_N$is connected".
Base case: for $N=1$, $P(N)$ is immediately true because $U_1 = A_1$.
Induction: suppose that for $N\in \mathbb N$, $P(N)$ is true, i.e $U_N$ is connected. Let $x,y\in U_{N+1} = U_N \cup A_{N+1}$.

Case 1: $x,y\in U_N$. Then $x\sim y$ as $P(N)$ is true.
Case 2: $x,y\in A_{N+1}$. Then $x\sim y$ as $A_{N+1}$ is connected.
Case 3: $x\in U_N$, $y\in A_{N+1}$. The property supposed by the question statement gives the existence of $z\in U_N \cap A_{N+1}$. Then $x\sim z$ as $x,z\in U_N$, and $z\sim y$ as $y,z\in A_{N+1}$. Thus $x\sim y$ by transitivity.
Case 4: $x\in A_{N+1}$, $y\in U_N$. Apply case $3$ by switching $x$ and $y$.

We conclude that for any $x,y\in U_{N+1}$, $x\sim y$. Thus $U_{N+1}$ is connected and $P(N+1)$ is true.
Conclusion: $U_N$ is connected for any $N\in \mathbb N$ by the principle of induction.
Let now $x,y\in U$. There exists $m,n\in \mathbb N$ such that $x\in U_m$ and $y\in U_n$. Then $P(N)$ with $N = \max(m,n)$ shows that $x\sim y$. Thus $U$ is connected.

Thank you! Much appreciated
